# Symfony: generate assetics

Tags: shell, symfony, capistrano, assetic

I use Capistrano and Symfony plugin ( https://github.com/capistrano/symfony ) for my deployment (I have Symfony 2.7). But, my CSS is wrong. I think assetic is not generated.

I used default **deploy.rb** and added ACL commands for chmod.

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, 'Dometech.fr'
set :repo_url, 'ssh://git@37.187.154.125:9325/var/www/depotsGit/dometech.git/'

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/dev/Dometech'

set :symfony_directory_structure, 2

namespace :deploy do
    after "deploy:updated" , "composer:install"

    # Clear ACL only before switching version
    before "deploy:publishing" , "symfony:fixes_acl"
end

namespace :symfony do
    desc "Add ACL on cache directory"
    task :fixes_acl do
    on roles :web do
        execute :setfacl, "-R -m u:www-data:rwX #{fetch(:release_path)}/app/cache #{fetch(:release_path)}/app/logs"
    end
    end
end
```

Can you help me **for assetic**?

Comment: "my Css is wrong" --- do you honestly think it's a comprehensive problem description?

Comment: @zerkms No, but “my Css is wrong ... I think assetic is not generated” is.

Comment: @Olivier "I think it's not generated" is also not an explanations. "I know it has not" would be. We're engineers, stop guessing

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Symfony Capistrano plugin [removed Assetic support](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/blob/b0d7009c70b0677c3d8af759ab6c612bb5893024/CHANGELOG.md), so you should add a task to your `deploy.rb` to take care of it. You can probably just take [what was removed](https://github.com/capistrano/symfony/commit/c3a729051260cdfc7e377f732be719c3cc9f5447):

```
set :assetic_dump_flags,  ''

namespace :assetic do
  desc "Dump assets with Assetic"
  task :dump do
    on release_roles(:all) do
      symfony_console "assetic:dump", fetch(:assetic_dump_flags)
    end
  end
end
```

and make sure it’s invoked with something like:

```
after 'deploy:updated', 'symfony:assetic:dump'
```